# mongodb 3 on ubuntu 15.04 Have to manualy start mongod service after every reboot

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-15.04

I used to have mongodb 2.6.3 and mongod service was always working. Yesterday I updated to mongodb 3.0.3 and if I type `mongo` in terminal I get this:

```
2015-06-06T10:24:51.679+0200 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to     127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-06-06T10:24:51.682+0200 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

I have to `service mongod start` after every reboot. Is there a way to fix this?

P.S. I was asked for the output of `initctl list`, here it is:

```
gnome-keyring-gpg stop/waiting
indicator-application stop/waiting
unicast-local-avahi stop/waiting
update-notifier-crash stop/waiting
upstart-udev-bridge start/running, process 1766
jayatana stop/waiting
update-notifier-hp-firmware stop/waiting
xsession-init stop/waiting
dbus start/running, process 1775
update-notifier-cds stop/waiting
gnome-keyring-ssh stop/waiting
gnome-session (Unity) start/running, process 1852
ssh-agent stop/waiting
unity7 start/running, process 1857
unity-voice-service stop/waiting
upstart-dbus-session-bridge start/running, process 1810
indicator-messages start/running, process 2007
logrotate stop/waiting
indicator-bluetooth start/running, process 2008
unity-panel-service start/running, process 1859
hud start/running, process 1846
im-config start/running
notify-cgmanager stop/waiting
unity-gtk-module stop/waiting
session-migration stop/waiting
upstart-dbus-system-bridge start/running, process 1827
at-spi2-registryd start/running, process 1850
indicator-power start/running, process 2009
update-notifier-release stop/waiting
indicator-datetime start/running, process 2010
indicator-keyboard start/running, process 2011
unity-settings-daemon start/running, process 1848
indicator-sound start/running, process 2012
upstart-file-bridge start/running, process 1828
gnome-keyring stop/waiting
gnome-settings-daemon stop/waiting
window-stack-bridge start/running, process 1787
indicator-printers start/running, process 2014
re-exec stop/waiting
upstart-event-bridge stop/waiting
unity-panel-service-lockscreen stop/waiting
indicator-session start/running, process 2016
```

Comment: Con you show us the output of `initctl list` ?

Answer (score 0):

You mongodb server isn't configured to start automatically.

On ubuntu using systemd, you must use :
`systemctl enable mongodb`

[Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) is some official documentation

Comment: `initctl: Не удается подключиться к Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: В соединении отказано
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'binfmt-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
`

Comment: Try 
`systemctl daemon-reload`
`sudo rm /etc/init.d/mongodb`

Comment: did that. When I ran `update-rc.d mongodb defaults` afterwards I get `update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d/mongodb`

Comment: And now : `systemctl enable mongodb`

Comment: `Failed to execute operation: Operation not supported`